# getting wrong time delta in python

Tags: python, datetime

I am subtracting two dates in python 2.7 and getting wrong result in seconds. Apparently difference between these dates  is more than 24h which is 86400s. But I am getting 44705s, why is that and how to fix it ?

```
>>> date1
datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 22, 11, 41, 28)
>>> date2
datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 20, 23, 16, 23)
>>> (date1-date2).seconds
44705
```

Comment: Maybe you want `(date1 - date2).total_seconds()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `.seconds` will only give you the seconds component of the [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) object, which only takes into account seconds, minutes, and hours (see docs for more detail). If you want the entire `timedelta` in seconds, call [`total_seconds`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds).

```
>>> (date1 - date2).total_seconds()  
131105.0
```

Comment: great...now  not sure which answer to reward

Comment: @irom Well, if it helps, I did post in the comments first :p It's up to you.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I'm not sure how to explain this, I can't seem to put it into words too well. What do you recommend?

Comment: Sounds good now. Just maybe make it a link to [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta)?

Answer (score 1):

`date1-date2` is `datetime.timedelta(1, 44705)`.  You're only looking at the seconds portion.  Look at the days portion too.